# String Fails to pass between two activities

Tags: java, android, string, http

I'm passing two strings between two activities and for some strange reason, the strings aren't being passed. I've done all the correct protocols and nothing seems to work, despite tinkering around with the code for several hours, I'm sure it's an simple solution, but I have no clue, what's so ever.

1st Class:

```
public class LogIn extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button ok, back, exit;
    TextView result;
    EditText pword;
    String password;
    EditText uname;
    String username;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Login button clicked
        ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        ok.setOnClickListener(this);

        result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl_result);

    } 
    //create bracket.

    public void postLoginData() {
        uname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
        uname.getText().toString();


        pword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_password);
        pword.getText().toString();
        Bundle basket = new Bundle();
        basket.putString("keypass", password);
        basket.putString("keyuname", username);
        Intent a = new Intent(LogIn.this, ChatService.class );
        a.putExtras(basket);
        startActivity(a);


        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        /* login.php returns true if username and password is equal to saranga */
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://gta5news.com/login.php");

        try {
            // Add user name and password


            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            Log.w("HttpPost(Login)", "Execute HTTP Post Request(Login 1)");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            String str = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent())
                    .toString();
            Log.w("HttpPost", str);

            if (str.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
                Log.w("HttpPost(Login2)", "TRUE");
                result.setText("Login successful");
                Intent login = new Intent(LogIn.this, ChatService.class);
                startActivity(login);

            }else {
                Log.w("HttpPost(Login(3)", "FALSE");
                result.setText(str);
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        String line = "";
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
        // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        // Read response until the end
        try {
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                total.append(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Return full string
        return total;
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view == ok) {

            postLoginData();
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(pword.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
        // Click end
    }
    // if statement
}

// class ends here
```

2nd class:

```
public class ChatService extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    BufferedReader in = null;
    String data = null;
    List headlines;
    List links;
    String GotPass;
    String GotUname;




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //get strings
        Bundle gotData = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(gotData !=null) {
        GotPass = gotData.getString("keypass");
        GotUname = gotData.getString("keyuname");


        try {
            //listview method
            ContactsandIm();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            CheckLogin();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }


    private void CheckLogin() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
// posts login data from "LogIn" class
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                /* login.php returns true if username and password is equal to saranga */
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://gta5news.com/login.php");

                try {
                    // Add user name and password


                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", GotUname));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", GotPass));
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    // Execute HTTP Post Request
                    Log.w("HttpPost(Login)", "Execute HTTP Post Request(ChatService 1)");
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                    String str = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent())
                            .toString();
                    Log.w("HttpPost", str);

                    if (str.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
                        Log.w("HttpPost(ChatService 2)", "TRUE");
                        // make toast if str.equals("True")
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Yayayaya, loged in", Toast.LENGTH_LONG );


                    }else {
                        Log.w("HttpPost(ChatService 3", "FALSE");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    }

                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
                String line = "";
                StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
                // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                // Read response until the end
                try {
                    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                        total.append(line);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // Return full string
                return total;
            }

    public void ContactsandIm() throws URISyntaxException,
            ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        headlines = new ArrayList();

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BufferedReader in = null;
        String data = null;

        HttpClient get = new DefaultHttpClient();
        URI website = new URI("http://www.gta5news.com/test.php");
        HttpGet webget = new HttpGet();
        webget.setURI(website);
        HttpResponse response = get.execute(webget);
        Log.w("HttpPost", "Execute HTTP Post Request");
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity()
                .getContent()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String l ="";
        String nl ="";
        while ((l =in.readLine()) !=null) {
            sb.append(l + nl);  
        }
        in.close();
         data = sb.toString();
         if(data.contains("null"));
         ListView lv = getListView();
         lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        headlines.add(data);


        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, headlines);

        setListAdapter(adapter);



    }

    // end bracket for "ContactsandIm"

}
```

Comment: what exactly is the problem? the strings are not in the bundle? the app crashes? etc. more info is required.

Comment: The strings are not in the bundle, sorry for not making that clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way.

```
    Intent a = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
    a.putExtra("String1", "Hello World");
    context.startActivity(a);
```

and

```
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String s1 = extras.getString("String1");
```

Comment: This is only a snippet. you have to use it in the correct place and check for null references etc. Basically my point was use this method to add your extras to the intent instead of adding them to a bundle which you then add to the intent. It works perfectly well for me.

Comment: I know, I implemented your code snippet and all the null references and yet, it still wouldn't work.

Comment: Anyone else, that can give me an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You should add both 2 activity in Mainfest.xml file

Answer (score 0):

Check have you register your activity in manifest file.